# Tagged union type including ManyToManyField and model constraints

Tags: django, django-models

Django ORM seems not to permit constraints on ManyToManyField.

```py
class Component(ComponentMetaData):
    class Type(models.IntegerChoices):
        Part = 0
        Components = 1

    type = models.IntegerField(
        choices=Type.choices,
    )
    components = models.ManyToManyField(
        "self",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    def clean(self) -> None:
        if self.type == 0 and self.components:
            raise ValidationError("Parts could not have components.") 
        return super().clean()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=(
                    Q(type = 0) & 
                    Q(components__isnull = True)
                ) | (
                    Q(type = 1) 
                    # componenets only fields
                ),
                name = "components_enum"
            )
        ]
```

Migration attempt with the above model results in the error below;

```
ERRORS:
myapp.Component: (models.E013) 'constraints' refers to a ManyToManyField 'components', but ManyToManyFields are not permitted in 'constraints'.
```

Does anyone know why this is not permitted and what should one do if one would like to keep a ManyToManyField empty on some condition based on the values of other fields?

---

UPDATE 2023-01-24

Following the advise of @Selcuk, I tried below.

```py
class Component(ComponentMetaData):
    class TypeTag(models.IntegerChoices):
        Part = 0
        Components = 1

    type_tag = models.IntegerField(
        choices=TypeTag.choices,
    )
    child_components = models.ManyToManyField(
        "self",
        through="ComponentRelation",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name="parent_component",
        symmetrical=False,
    )

    def clean(self) -> None:
        if self.type_tag == 0 and self.components:
            raise ValidationError("Parts could not have components.")
        return super().clean()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=(
                    Q(type_tag=0)
                    # part only fields
                ) | (
                    Q(type_tag=1)
                    # componenets only fields
                ),
                name="component_enum"
            )
        ]


class ComponentRelation(models.Model):
    from_component = models.ForeignKey(
        "Component",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="from_component",
    )
    to_component = models.ForeignKey(
        "component",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="to_component",
    )

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=(
                    Q(from_component__type_tag = 1)
                ),
                name="component_relation"
            )
        ]
```

It results following error on migration.

```
myapp.ComponentRelation: (models.E041) 'constraints' refers to the joined field 'from_component__type_tag'.
```

It seems model constraint is a mere interface of DB functionality and could only include constraints for a single row, but no inter-table, complex constraints, generally speaking.

Is there any other way to do this??

Comment: Haven't tried myself, but it is probably because ManyToMany fields do not correspond to actual columns in the database. Not sure if this applies to your use case, but you may try explicitly creating a [`through`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) table and add the constraint there.

Comment: @Selcuk I tried your solution. However, it seems model constraints can't include information on another table. Please check the updated question.

Comment: Bugger. No idea how to implement this using constraints. You may consider overriding the `save` method or using signals to implement your own validation.